# Defining syntax for block comments C++

Tags: c++, exception, infinite-loop

The following is the syntax I defined for line and block comments

```
if (currentChar == '/')
        {
            if (miniLangInput[lookAheadIndex + 1] == '/') //line comment
            {
                while (currentChar != '\n')
                {
                    lookAheadIndex += 1;
                    currentChar = miniLangInput[lookAheadIndex];
                }
                return Lexer::token(TOK_LINECOMMENT);
            }
            else if (miniLangInput[lookAheadIndex + 1] == '*') //block comment
            {
                bool reached = false;
                do
                {
                    lookAheadIndex += 1;
                    currentChar = miniLangInput[lookAheadIndex];
                    if (currentChar == '*' && miniLangInput[lookAheadIndex + 1] == '/')
                    {
                        lookAheadIndex += 1;
                        currentChar = miniLangInput[lookAheadIndex];
                        reached = true;
                    }
                } while (reached == false); //while (lastChar != '/');
                lookAheadIndex += 1;
                return Lexer::token(TOK_BLOCKCOMMENT);
            }
            else
            {
                lookAheadIndex += 1;
                return Lexer::token(TOK_SLASH);
            }
        }
```

However, if at the end of the input string an open block comment is encountered without its closing block (i.e( /* ) ) the program crashes resulting in the following error:

Debug assertion failed, string subscript out of range.

This is happening since the while clause is not met and therefore results in an infinite loop.

Is there an exception class I can use to prevent the program from crashing? I tried enclosing the do while in a try catch however, this did not have any effect.

Comment: You just need a range-check on `lookAheadIndex` before evaluating `miniLangInput[lookAheadIndex + 1]`. But there is no syntax for block and inline comments. They are ignorable lexical elements, just like white space. You should be just eating them up, not returning them to the parser.

Comment: EJP: Depends if this is the parser for a compiler, or something like doxygen .

Comment: thanks EJP this was solved by checking the position in the input string and if the last character is consumed than it breaks from the loop. This is a parser for a compiler, however I need to specify the syntax to only accept comments of the form // or /**/ and not something like this /*